Add button in the header in report tree
I need to add a new button to the header panel of my report, but it's not working. The following code allows the module to update without errors, but when I look at the report page, it gets completely stuck; it remains blank and doesn't throw any errors. What am I doing wrong?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates>
  <t t-name="stock_button_report.ListView.Buttons" t-inherit="web.ListView">
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-set-slot='control-panel-additional-actions']" position="after">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px;"
        t-on-click="OnTestClick">
        Example
      </button>
    </xpath>
  </t>
</templates>

JS
/** @odoo-module */
import { ListController } from "@web/views/list/list_controller";
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { listView } from "@web/views/list/list_view";
export class StockButtonListController extends ListController {
  setup() {
    super.setup();
  }
  OnTestClick() {}
}
registry.category("views").add("stock_button_report", {
  ...listView,
  Controller: StockButtonListController,
  buttonTemplate: "stock_button_report.ListView.Buttons",
});

View
<record id="view_report_history_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">report.history.tree</field>
    <field name="model">report.history</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Historial de Informes">
            <!-- <header>
                <button name="action_for_wizard" string="Action" object="action" />
            </header> -->
            <field name="name" />
            <field name="create_date" />
            <field name="user_id" />
            <field name="file_name" />
            <button name="action_download_report" type="object" icon="fa-download"
                string="Descargar" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="view_grouped_stock_moves_inherited_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">report.history.tree.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">report.history</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="view_report_history_tree" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="js_class">stock_button_report</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

Thanks for the help

You need to inherit the web.ListView.Buttons template and use the primary inheritance mode
Example:
<t t-name="stock_button_report.ListView.Buttons" t-inherit="web.ListView.Buttons" t-inherit-mode="primary">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_list_buttons')]" position="inside">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px;"
        t-on-click="OnTestClick">
        Example
      </button>
    </xpath>
</t>

